# Intellij + Groovy + Spock, cannot resolve symbol 'spock'

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, groovy, spock

I am using Spock framework for tests and everything worked great, until today; I do not know what happened. Intellij says "Configure Groovy sdk" so I downloaded groovy sdk 2.4.9 and configured it, but in my test class in import line:

import spock.lang.Specification

intellij says "cannot resolve symbol spock". Any suggestions?

Comment: You're probably missing a required lib/dependency fork spock. Download it an configure.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Problem solved. It turned out that someone on another branch forgot to configure the spock, now everything works great. Thanks for advice!

Comment: @JadenKorr please add your found solution as an answer and accept it or delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm playing with spock tests in an Intellij gradle environment and could not resolve this until I added the following line to my dependencies in build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.spock.framework:spock-core:1.0-groovy2.4'
```